# Log errors into error table in insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, error-logging, dml

I came across an error invalid identifier in the error table even though the fields are present in the error table. The below is my test code for your reference. Any update absolutely appreciated.

```sql
Insert into test1 
(a,b,e)
Select a,b,c||d e from 
  (Select c.a, d.b, d.c, c.d 
     From 
       (select e.a,e.b, f.c, d.d from 
         Test2 e, Test 2 f where
           e.id = f.id) c ) v
Log errors into test1_err
  (‘Batch :’
     || to_char(v.a)
     || to_char(v.b)
     || ‘;’
   ) Reject Limit Unlimited;
```

> SQL Error: ORA:-00904: "v.a": invalid indentifier

Comment: you can start with fixing the quotes.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: the quotes in `‘Batch :’` and `‘;’` should be `''` per each.

Comment: Nope, that's the way it is in my original code ‘Batch :’

Comment: but *the way* violates the rule for Oracle

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan is right. The quote character for literal strings in Oracle is `'`, not `’`, regardless of what you had in your original code.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66236558/230471

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you created the table with the dbms_errlog package, the expression  you put in the '()' can contain the following as per [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423):

simple_expression

Specify the value to be used as a statement tag, so that you can identify the errors from this statement in the error logging table. The expression can be either a text literal, a number literal, or a general SQL expression such as a bind variable. You can also use a function expression if you convert it to a text literal — for example, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE).

so you cannot put column values. These are added to the table by the kernel, no need to add them yourself.